# No Entity Framework Provider Found

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml, entity-framework-6

i have a project that is been started two months ago ! i'm using [LASG]:https://layerguidance.codeplex.com/ Architecture for my Solution ! 
i'm working in my solution well since i have received the " No Entity Framwork provider found for the ADO.net Provider with invarient name 'System.Data.SqlClient' "

the application config file contain the full block of provider

this is my app.config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MASTERGESTION" connectionString="Data Source=ZZZZ\ZZZZZ;Initial Catalog=XXXXXX;User ID=YY;Password=ZZZZZZ" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I copied the project in other computer, after building the solution, it start normally and without provider error

I rebuild the solution many times, i re-add references manually with no response!

Any help please? i loose six hours for no reason

Comment: I think your  defaultConnectionFactory shouldn't be `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory` but instead `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory` unless perhaps you have LocalDb installed also.

Answer (score 0):

The `defaultConnectionFactory` shouldn't be:

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory
```

Instead make it:

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory
```

I assume it worked on the second machine as that has LocalDb installed and the first one doesn't.

Comment: the same problem after i edit the connectionFactory ! 
The progam did't detect the 'System.Data.SqlClient' provider in the application config file, that's the problem ! i just said that the project worked well, oops after no change i have this exception

Comment: Do you have references in your project for both `EntityFramework` and `EntityFramework.SqlServer`?

Comment: In which folder are the DLLs for these references?

Comment: the Data Folder contain this references ! exactly at Project.Data Project

Comment: I would remove the references to both of these libraries and install the version from Nuget. In the package manager console, run this `Install-Package EntityFramework`

Comment: i always add entity framwork from nuget package ! now , i re-install those references , i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of

```
User ID=YY;Password=ZZZZZZ
```

to use

```
Integrate Security=True
```

also add in `<context>`

```
<context type="tablename, databasename">
        <databaseInitializer type="databasename.Migrations.tablenameInitializer, databasename" />
      </context>
```

Comment: the project didn't arrived to localise the provider in the entity framework section until now !